# Named Config files - Hot or Not?

Tags: version-control, configuration, app-config

I've chosen a solution to our config file process and need to justify it. I'd appreciate insight and criticism. Thanks!

**Problem:**
Our web applications have a single application.cfm file containing variables and conditionals

```
<cfif url = "*dev*" or "jargon123">
    this is a dev enviroment, do devy things
</cfif>
```

So a dev new to the application will deploy a local instance. Fire it up and start poking around. Problem is that the config file contains production values. It starts hitting production data and sending production emails. Also, since the url they are hitting is http://App_name:PORT or http://localhost - the dev conditionals are never set. So there is more production stuff happening in dev.

**What other co-workers want:**

- A Switch statement. The app.cfm will lead with an environment variable set to "development", then declares general variables. It will then go into a switch statement and declare environment specific variables. I disagree with this method as some of our config files are 100 - 250 lines. That can be a massive Switch statement I don't want to muck around in.

**My chosen solution:**

- App.cfm has been deleted and removed from version control. We now have multiple Applicaiton.Enviroment.cfm files, i.e. Applicaiton.Prod.cfm, Application.Dev.cfm, Applicaiton.MyName.cfm etc. This file contains all of the environment specific data. I moved Production specific settings out of conditionals and into App.Prod.cfm. Deployments to new environments are now 1. Duplicate App.Dev.cfm as App.Me.cfm and commit. 2. Update all variables to my personal data (email, login, etc) 3. Duplicate App.me.cfm as App.cfm and use for config file.

I won't go into why I'm not doing the other solutions but here is my reason for my solutions:

- Forces the deployment engineer into selecting the right config file for the environment. The app won't work without an app.cfm
- Limits potential of user error. Scenario would be a user copies data into a new environment mode and accidentally copies production content.
- It's cleaner and easier to work with - config value's are completely compartmentalized from each other.

I've found a lot of articles on working with environment specific config files but not why they are better. That's the motivation behind this post.

Answer (score 1):

I would also delete the production config and provide only development versions of the config file. Reasons:

- a config file could contain security relevant data
- many developers are just lazzy, if the application runs, the don't care about the config
- if the developer do not use the currently provided mechanisms (the dev url), who could you be sure they set the environment variable?
- using the live config during testing could result in active debug options on the production later (forgotten to remove from configuration)

Answer (score 1):

You (development) need to be able to switch between different configurations for different versions of your software at any time.  If each setup has its own configuration file, this is a lot easier than if they all share the same file.

If you have all configuration in a single file, you have to read the whole big file, deciding which parts to ignore.  This is messier than just reading the whole file.

(I assume that you can have multiple versions of the software installed concurrently in different locations on the same machine.  If you can't, you have a bigger problem.  But even so, having separate configuration files is beneficial.)

Those are strong 'pros' for separate configuration files - they outweigh the minor 'con': you have to identify where the configuration file is by some mechanism or another.  It might be via an environment variable or via a command-line option, with a suitable default if neither is specified.  Command-line should override environment.